# Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `store` was not specified in `Provider`. in Provider

Tags: react-redux

I am a beginner in using react-redux, after I add <Provider> to my code,

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

var BlogApp = require("./components/BlogApp");
var Main = require("./components/Main");
var NewPost = require("./components/NewPost");
var PostDetail = require("./components/PostDetail");
var Login = require("./components/Login");
var Signup = require("./components/Signup");

import { store } from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.render((
  **<Provider store={store}>**
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/blog" component={BlogApp}>
        <IndexRoute component={Main} />
        <Route path="newpost" component={NewPost} />
        <Route path=":postId" component={PostDetail} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    </Router>
  **</Provider>**
  ),
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

the browser console report two warnings below:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `store` was not specified in `Provider`.
>   Warning: Failed childContext type: Required child context `store` was not specified in `Provider`. in Provider

The version info related as below:

> "react": "^15.3.2",
>       "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
>       "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
>       "react-router": "^2.8.1",
>       "redux": "^3.6.0",

related files:

**store.js:**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

import { blogReducer } from "../reducers/blogReducer";

const store = createStore(blogReducer);

export default store;
```

**blogReducer.js:**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const state = {
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "test",
      date: "2016.10.17",
      summary: "test"
    }
  ]
};

function posts(state = [], action) {
  // TODO: temporory code
  return state;
}

/* TODO: must using export, if not the browser will report error below
 bundle.js:10988 Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.(…) */
export const blogReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: posts
});

export default blogReducer;
```

I have no idea how to fix it, can you give me a solution? TKS

Comment: the store attribute is spelled wrong

Comment: thanks for your tip, after I update to "store", the warnings are still there.

Comment: looks fine now, what's in your store file?

Comment: I update store and reducer files in my post

Comment: I found the reason, it's because the wrong import statement: "import { store } from "./store/store";", should be "import store from "./store/store";", Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, It's because the wrong import statement: 
"import { store } from "./store/store";"
It should be "import store from "./store/store";"